# Prove that a matrix with a given characteristic polynomial is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Matrix $A$ is defined over real number.

Characteristic polynomial : $p(x)=(x+3)^2(x-1)(x-5)$

It also known that :

$$\text{rank}(A+2I)+\text{rank}(A+3I)+\text{rank}(A-5I)=9$$

- prove $A$ diagonalize.

**My solution**

- $-3,1,5$ are eigenvalues, using the characteristic polynomial we can conclude that matrix $A$ is $4 \times 4$
- Since eigenvalue $1,5$ has algebraic multiplicity of $1$, we can conclude that geometric multiplicity is also $1$ hence:

$$\text{rank}(I+A)=3$$

$$\text{rank}(5I-A)=3$$

I don't find a way to continue from here.

Comment: What do you mean by $p(A+2I)+p(A+3I)+p(A-5I)=9$?  How can a matrix be equal to $9$? Do you mean $9I$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $p(A)$=rank of matrix A$

Comment: You should use \rho or some other symbol for the rank of a matrix.

Comment: $-3$, not $ 3 $

Comment: @Belgi Your right mistyped, thanks

Comment: Since $-2$ is not an eigenvalue, you have $\operatorname{rk} (A+2I) = 4$, which means $\operatorname{rk} (A+3I)+ \operatorname{rk} (A-5I) = 5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picking up from where you left off.

From $\text{rank}(A-5I)=3$ and from $\text{rank}(A+2I)+\text{rank}(A+3I)+\text{rank}(A-5I)=9$ you get
$$\text{rank}(A+2I)+\text{rank}(A+3I)=6.$$

Now prove that $A+2I$ is invertible. What does that tell you about the rank of $A+2I$?

Infer that $\text{rank}(A+3I)=2$. What does that tell you about the geometric multiplicity of $-3$?

Conclude.

Comment: Could I prove that $A+2I$ since 0 is not an eigenvalue $\rightarrow$ A is invertible, since 2 is not an eigenvalue $\rightarrow$ A+2I is invertible?

Comment: @JaVaPG I find your wording confusing. It's not $2$ that matters here, it's $-2$. Since $-2$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$, it follows that $A-(-2I)$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** with such a characteristic polynomial, the matrix is congruent to either
$$
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-3 & 1 & 0 &0\\
0 & -3 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0 & 1 &0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &5\end{array} \right)
$$
or 
$$   \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-3 & 0 & 0 &0\\
0 & -3 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0 & 1 &0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &5\end{array} \right)$$

Then in each case, compute $P(A)$ in this  new base.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The rank of $A - \lambda I$ is $n$ minus (the number of Jordan blocks of $A$ that are associated with $\lambda$).